# How to remove registered jquery file in Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

While working with Yii2, I am facing a problem with jquery files.
In layout I have registered a `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` file. But in inner page
as use `ActiveForm` then it includes jquery file from assets as well.

Is there any way to remove `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` on any page while using `ActiveForm` ?

Many Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should modify assetManager component config :

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
                    'js' => [
                        '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',  // use custom jquery
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

It will load a custom jquery (no need to register it).

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles